# Is it possible to create a polarized 3d website?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, webgl

is it possible to create a website which would display in 3d similar to 3d games or movies? What if I were to modulate the website using some sort of css or webgl technique?

Something which i've found quite interesting is adjusting the angle of an image e.g:
[image: http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lg7502uXDs1qdmci6o1_250.gif]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polarised would require APIs that don't exist (yet). You can however play with analglyphic techniques.

I made this 3d spinning cube (requires a browser with 3d transforms to work) that uses red cyan glasses to work: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/demos/3d.php

It kinda works!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a 3d website is possible, but hard, using red/cyan anaglyph glasses. Getting 3d using active shutter glasses is perhaps theoretically possible, but almost certainly unfeasible without huge timing issues. Polarized glasses is impossible without using a projector with a split image lens and polarized filters (or two projectors).

Comment: Maybe if the video hardware supports 3d and something like WebGL provides an API to access that? E.g. http://opablo.com.ar/webgl/webgl3dplayer/ and http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/tag/webgl/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Latest stable version of Chrome 9 now has built-in support for WebGL. Some of famous example will be [Aquarium](http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html), [Jellyfish](http://aleksandarrodic.com/p/jellyfish/) and even [Virtual globe](http://www.webglearth.com/).

Comment: Since he mentions polarization in the title, I don't think he's talking about just OpenGL 3D, but also full stereoscopic 3D.